# jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]

Tags: angularjs, npm-start

I get this error and a blank page on the browser when I run my page using npm start

> jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]
>   [http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.4/$injector/modulerr?p0=blocJams&p1=Error%3…ogleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.6.4%2Fangular.min.js%3A22%3A179](http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.4/$injector/modulerr?p0=blocJams&p1=Error%3%E2%80%A6ogleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.6.4%2Fangular.min.js%3A22%3A179)
>   `at angular.js:38
>       at angular.js:4920
>       at q (angular.js:403)
>       at g (angular.js:4880)
>       at eb (angular.js:4802)
>       at c (angular.js:1914)
>       at Sc (angular.js:1935)
>       at ue (angular.js:1820)
>       at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (angular.js:33367)
>       at j (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2)`

here is my app.js

```
(function() {
    function config($stateProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $locationProvider
            .html5Mode({
                enabled: true,
                requireBase: false
        });

        $stateProvider
         .state('landing', {
             url: '/',
             controller: 'LandingCtrl as landing',
             templateUrl: '/templates/landing.html'
         })
         .state('album', {
             url: '/album',
             controller: 'AlbumCtrl as album',
             templateUrl: '/templates/album.html'
         })

        .state('collection', {
            url: '/collection',
            controller: 'CollectionCtrl as collection',
            templateUrl: '/templates/collection.html'
        });

    }

    angular
        .module('blocJams', ['ui.router'])
        .config(config);
})();
```

here is my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="blocJams">
<head lang="en">
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <title>Bloc Jams Angular</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,800,600,700,300">
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/styles/normalize.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/styles/main.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/styles/landing.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/styles/collection.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/styles/album.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/styles/player_bar.css">
</head>
<body>

    <nav class="navbar"> <!-- navigation bar -->
             <a ui-sref="landing" class="logo"><!-- I changed href="album.html" to ui-sref="album" -->
                <img src="assets/images/bloc_jams_logo.png" alt="bloc jams logo">
             </a>
             <div class="links-container">
                 <a ui-sref="collection" class="navbar-link">Collection</a><!-- I changed href="collection.html" to ui-sref="collection" -->
             </div>
    </nav>

    <ui-view></ui-view>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.4.2/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/buzz/1.2.0/buzz.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/scripts/app.js"></script>
    <script src="/scripts/services/Fixtures.js"></script>
    <script src="/scripts/services/SongPlayer.js"></script>
    <script src="/scripts/controllers/LandingCtrl.js"></script>
    <script src="/scripts/controllers/CollectionCtrl.js"></script>
    <script src="/scripts/controllers/AlbumCtrl.js"></script>
    <script src="/scripts/controllers/PlayerBarCtrl.js"></script>
    <script src="/scripts/directives/seekBar.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: could you share the point where you define and inject dependencies to your module blocJams?